# Remove a line if it contains more than 3 spaces

Tags: if-statement, awk, line

I have a text file in the form

```
sadsadsad sadsadsadd sadasdsadad
```

some of the lines in there contain an addition space in the middle of the second column such as

```
sadsadsad sads adsadd sadasdsadad
```

Can I use awk to look at the file and delete the line if there's more than 2 spaces on a particular line?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `awk` for that, a simple `sed` will do:

```
sed -e '/ .* .* /d'
```

If you want `awk` specifically, you can do something like this:

```
!/ .* .* / {
    print;
}
```

You can also customize the regexp to be more precise, maybe by using in both cases `/ [^ ]+ [^ ]+ /`. Or even, as jkerian proposes in another answer, just use `NF`.

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a regex you can create to do this with a regex match with sed or awk... but this works

```
awk '{if ($4 == "") print}' input_file
```

Another alternative is to use the NF variable

```
awk '{if (NF < 4) print}' input_file
```

Comment: or even `awk 'NF < 4' input_file`